# A expanding road problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to understand a concept mentioned in the following youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QfOF0bRBFJ4&feature=youtu.be&t=2471, this link will start playing the video from the relevant part onward.

The problem mentioned in the video is as follows.

A target is placed on a road which is 100 meters long, a man standing 99 meters away from the target starts walking toward the target. The man covers 1 meter  with every step he takes per second and while he is walking the road stretches by 1 meter every 100 meters, every second. How long will it take for the man to reach its target?

The video claims the man would reach the target in 460 seconds. But i don't see how that is the case.

The first 10 steps makes the target at 98 meters ,the next 10 steps makes it 97, next 10 steps at 96...so on and so forth, so if this is the pattern then it should take more than 460 seconds to reach the target. Any help in making the math clear is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of posting links you should paraphrase the problem so more people are likely to answer and not move on.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion i have updated my question.

Comment: One has to be really careful in defining how the road stretches. Presumably it does so uniformly, but with respect to which reference point (coordinate)?

Comment: I think it stretches in the direction of the target, otherwise the claim made by the video that the target is  98 meters afar after 10 seconds doesn’t hold.

Comment: You missed the narrator's "almost". when describing the 2nd step. He gains a little more than 1 meter per 10 steps.

Answer (score 0):

You can find more detailed descriptions by searching for [ant on a rubber rope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant_on_a_rubber_rope).

You tagged pre-calculus, but a full explanation of this requires calculus. The simplest explanation without calculus is only an approximation: Instead of the road stretching while he is walking, they alternate: He takes a 1 sec step on an un-stretching road, and then the road instaneously stretches its 1 sec amount.

He starts at $99$ m, steps to $98$ m, then the road stretches by $1\%$ (its $100$ meter length stretches to $101$ meters). This stretch increases all lengths by $1\%$, so that $98$ m becomes $98.98$ meters. he then steps forward again to $97.98$ m, and the road stretches another $1\%$, making putting him at $98.9598$. Here is how the first few 20 steps look:
$$\begin{array} {c|c|c|c}
\text{Time} & \text{Position} & \text{After Step} & \text{After Stretch}\\\hline
0&99&98&98.98\\
1&98.98&97.98&98.9598\\
2&98.9598&97.9598&98.939398\\
3&98.939398&97.939398&98.91879198\\
4&98.91879198&97.91879198&98.8979799\\
5&98.8979799&97.8979799&98.8769597\\
6&98.8769597&97.8769597&98.8557293\\
7&98.8557293&97.8557293&98.83428659\\
8&98.83428659&97.83428659&98.81262945\\
9&98.81262945&97.81262945&98.79075575\\
10&98.79075575&97.79075575&98.76866331\\
11&98.76866331&97.76866331&98.74634994\\
12&98.74634994&97.74634994&98.72381344\\
13&98.72381344&97.72381344&98.70105157\\
14&98.70105157&97.70105157&98.67806209\\
15&98.67806209&97.67806209&98.65484271\\
16&98.65484271&97.65484271&98.63139114\\
17&98.63139114&97.63139114&98.60770505\\
18&98.60770505&97.60770505&98.5837821\\
19&98.5837821&97.5837821&98.55961992\\
20&98.55961992&97.55961992&98.53521612\end{array}$$

Slow going. 20 steps in, and he still hasn't gained a half meter. But note that the amount he does gain with each step is increasing. The table continues until:
$$\begin{array} {c|c|c|c}
389&5.050128574&4.050128574&4.09062986\\
390&4.09062986&3.09062986&3.121536158\\
391&3.121536158&2.121536158&2.14275152\\
392&2.14275152&1.14275152&1.154179035\\
393&1.154179035&0.154179035&0.155720825\\
394&0.155720825&-0.844279175&-0.852721966\\
395&-0.852721966&&\end{array}$$

So in this scenario, it takes him 395 seconds to reach his destination. This still differs from the $460$ seconds proclaimed by the video. But remember that this is only an approximation of the continuous scenario the video is discussing. We can improve the approximation by using smaller time increments. If you use $0.1$ second increments instead of $1 sec$, then at each increment, the man moves forward by $0.1$ meter, but the road stretches by $0.0996\%$ ($1.000996^{10} \approx 1.01$). Under these conditions, it takes $419.4$ seconds for the man to reach the end. So it is not unreasonable that as the time increment keeps getting smaller, the total time approaches $460$ seconds.

However, I do calculate a much slower start than the video says. This discrepancy does not appear to be due to the discrete treatment, as decreasing the time increment actually causes the start to slow down, not speed up to what the video says. Still, I cannot say if the discrepancy is my fault or theirs.

Comment: Nice explanation. Thanks a bunch. One small doubt though, when taking small increments of 0.1 second didn't quiet understand how the road stretches by 0.0996% ?

Comment: If the road stretches by a ratio $r$ in a step (that is, if the old length is $L$, then the new length is $rL$), then after $10$ steps, the length is $r^{10}L$. A $q\%$ increase corresponds to $r = 1 + \frac q{100}$ (because $rL = (1 + \frac q{100}) L = L + \frac q{100}L$, so the length increases by $q\%$). Since we are told that the length increases $1\%$ every second, we need $r^{10} = 1.01$ for our $0.1$ second steps, and the solution to that is $r \approx 1.000996$. Converting that back to a percentage gives $0.0996\%$

Comment: Perfect!.Thanks.